# If $X$ is a metric space, $A \subset X$ y $r\in \mathbb{R}^+$, then $V_r(A)=\{x\in X: d(x,A)\leq r\}$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $X$ is a metric space, $A \subset X$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}^+$, then $V_r(A)=\{x\in X: d(x,A)\leq r\}$ is closed.

My attempt: let $x\in V_{r}(A)$, by definition, for all $\epsilon>0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap V_{r}(A)\not =  \emptyset$, then exist $y$ such that $y\in B(x,\epsilon)$ and $y\in V_{r}(A)$ then $d(y,A)\leq r$ and $d(y,x)\leq \epsilon$ then $d(x,A)\leq d(y,A)+d(y,x)\leq r+\epsilon$

But I need $d(x,A)\leq r$

please!
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n \in V_r (A) $ and let $x_n \to x_0 .$ Then $d(x_n ,A)\leq r $ for all $n$ and hence by the continuity of the function $f(x) =d(x,A) $ we obtain that $d(x_0, A) \leq r$ so $x_0 \in V_r (A) $ and so $V_r (A) $ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

I often find it easier to prove that complements are open.  If $d(x, A) = r+\alpha$ with $\alpha \gt 0$, then by the triangle inequality, $B \left (x, \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \cap V_r(A) = \varnothing$, so $x$ (an arbitrary point of the complement) is in the interior of the complement.  The complement is therefore open, so $V_r(A)$ is closed.